# Can we say that $\mu^* (A) = \mu (A),$ for all $A \in \mathcal A$?

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation, outer-measure

Let $\mathcal A$ be an algebra of subsets of a set $X$ and $\mu : \mathcal A \longrightarrow [0,+\infty]$ be a measure on $\mathcal A.$ Define $\mu^* : \mathcal P(X) \longrightarrow [0,+\infty]$ by $$\mu^* (A) : = \text {inf}\ \left \{ \sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} \mu \left (A_j \right )\ :\ \bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} A_j \supseteq A,\ A_j \in \mathcal A \right \},\ \ \ \ A \subseteq X.$$ Then clearly $\mu^*$ is well-defined and it is called the outer measure of subsets of $X.$

With this definition in mind we can easily come up with some of the properties of $\mu^*.$

$(1)$ $\mu^* (\varnothing) = 0$ and $\mu^*(A) \geq 0,$ for all $A \subseteq X.$

$(2)$ $\mu^*$ is monotonic i.e. if $A \subseteq B \subseteq X$ then $\mu^* (A) \leq \mu^* (B).$

$(3)$ $\mu^*$ is countably sub-additive i.e. given $A \subseteq X$ and given a countable covering $\left \{A_j \right \}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ of $A$ by subsets of $X$ we have $$\mu^* (A) \leq \sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}\mu^*(A_j).$$

Also it is clear that $\mu^* (A) \leq \mu(A)$ as $\{A \}$ itself a countable covering of $A$ by elements of $\mathcal A.$ Can we say the other part of the inclusion to be true? i.e. can I say that $\mu(A) \leq \mu^*(A)$? I have watched a video recently in youtube which proves the result to be true. But I found a mistake in it. It argues as follows $:$

If $\mu^* (A) = +\infty$ then we have nothing to prove. So WLOG let us assume that $\mu^*(A) < +\infty.$ Let us fix $\varepsilon > 0$ arbitrarily. Then by the property of infimum $\exists$ a countable covering $\{A_j \}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ of $A$ by elements of $\mathcal A$ such that $$\mu^*(A) + \varepsilon > \sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} \mu (A_j).$$

Making $\varepsilon \to 0$ we have $$\mu^*(A) \geq \sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} \mu (A_j).$$

Now $\mu$ being a measure on $\mathcal A$ it is countably sub-additive. So we have $$\mu (A) \leq \sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} \mu (A_j).$$

This is the stage where I didn't understand the reasoning. How do we say that $\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} A_j \in \mathcal A$? $\mathcal A$ being an algebra it is only closed under finite unions but might not be closed under countable unions. Right? But then we cannot certainly invoke the concept of countable sub-additivity of $\mu$ here. Can anybody please make it clear to me? Any helpful suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much for your valuable time for reading.

**Source** $:$ https://youtu.be/6_RQ1c1VVBs?list=PLtKWB-wrvn4mbGE2XeUbnVw1cwAj4-f0C&t=699

Comment: The key question is what we mean by "a measure on $\mathcal{A}$".  Is it meant to be countably additive, or only finitely additive?

Comment: Note that for an algebra which is not a $\sigma$-algebra, "countably additive" is taken to apply only to sequences of sets in $\mathcal{A}$ whose union happens to also be in $\mathcal{A}$.  Under that assumption, you can prove that countable subadditivity does indeed hold, in the sense that if $A, A_j \in \mathcal{A}$ with $A \subset \bigcup A_j$ then $\mu(A) \le \sum \mu(A_j)$.

Comment: Measure means countably additive with measure of the empty set is $0.$

Comment: @Nate Eldredge that's my point. We can't say that $\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} A_j \in \mathcal A$ with certainty. Then how did the professor apply the countable sub-additive property of $\mu$ here? Isn't that wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, we cannot assert that $\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j \in \mathcal{A}$.  But we don't have to.

First note that $\mu$ enjoys the following countable sub-additivity property:

> (*) If $B_j, B \in \mathcal{A}$ and $B = \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty B_j$, then $\mu(B) \le \sum_{j=1}^\infty \mu(B_j)$.

This is proved by the usual "disjointification": define $C_j$ inductively as $C_1 = B_1$, $C_{j+1} = B_{j+1} \setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^j C_i$.  Then the $C_j$ are disjoint and $B = \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty C_j$ so by countable additivity $\mu(B) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \mu(C_j)$.  But we have $C_j \subseteq B_j$ so by finite additivity $\mu(C_j) \le \mu(B_j)$, hence $ \sum_{j=1}^\infty \mu(C_j) \le \sum_{j=1}^\infty \mu(B_j)$.

Now, returning to the original problem, apply property (*) with $B_j = A \cap A_j$.
We get $\mu(A) \le \sum_{j=1}^\infty \mu(B_j)$, and since $B_j \subseteq A_j$, we conclude $\mu(A) \le \sum_{j=1}^\infty \mu(A_j)$ as desired.

So we do indeed have the following improved countable sub-additivity property:

> (**) If $A_j, A \in \mathcal{A}$ and $A \subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j$, then $\mu(A) \le \sum_{j=1}^\infty \mu(A_j)$.  This holds whether $\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j \in \mathcal{A}$ or not.

This justifies the line of the proof that you were asking about.

Comment: Nice answer. This is quite satisfactory to me. Shouldn't the professor have mentioned it while discussing this?

Comment: @mathmaniac.: [He did](https://youtu.be/TB4BVWlI7v8?t=1609)

Comment: No. I already know that any measure is countably sub-additive. What I want to say is that he should have mentioned those $B_j$'s that you did in order to show the other way inequality. Isn't it so? Instead he proved it in a wrong way as you pointed out because $\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} A_j$ might not be included in the algebra $\mathcal A$ we have started with. The same mistake is crept in his book published by American Mathematical Society. Even editors completely ignored this mistake. Isn't it unexpected from a reputed publisher like AMS?

Comment: @mathmaniac.: I suppose you're referring to *An Introduction to Measure and Integration* by Inder K. Rana.  The book looks okay to me.  He defines "countably subadditive" as my statement (\*), with the assumption that the union is in the algebra, and so his proof that countably additive implies countably subadditive (Theorem 3.6.1 (iii)) seems fine.  Then he leaves it as Exercise 3.3.2 (ii) to show that (\*) implies (\*\*), the case where the union is not necessarily in the algebra.

Comment: And as far as the statement you ask about in the question, which I think is Proposition 3.7.4 (iv), he does do exactly the trick where you intersect with $A$, at the top of page 73 in my copy (second edition).

Comment: @mathmaniac.: Incidentally, I think you might be overestimating how much editing a graduate-level math textbook gets, even from a "reputable" publisher.  In particular, typically the editors won't go through the book line-by-line to check all the math.  That's still on the author.  Errors do occur and I think most people just learn to live with it - you sort it out, you report it, you pencil a note in your book and you move on.

Comment: Do you mean $C_j = B_j \setminus B_{j-1},$ for $j \geq 2\ $? Suppose we have three sets $B_1,B_2$ and $B_3.$ Then according to your definition $C_3 = B_3 \setminus (B_2 \setminus B_1)$ which might have non-empty intersection with $C_1 = B_1$ namely the portion $B_1 \cap B_3.$ How do you know that $B_1 \cap B_3 = \varnothing\ $?

Comment: @AntonioClaire: You're right, it's a mistake.  I actually mean $C_{j+1} = B_{j+1} \setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^j C_i$.  I'll fix it.